# Field type to select a parent item along with some child items

Tags: fieldtype

I have the following content structure. I want the parent and child relationship to be maintained post selection. If I use a Treelist and select a Region and some Locations, will the child items maintain the relation with the parent automatically? The image below shows the expected output, location1 and location3 have to be grouped under the parent 'Region1'.

[image]

Comment: No the hierarchy will not be stored as shown in the screenshot. You’ll need to have custom implementation to have this

Comment: Is it possible that the selected item in the right column be something like this: Location 1 - Region1, Location3 - Region1?